# If I open a Cursor in side a TRY then where should I close it?

Tags: sql-server

If I have this:

```
BEGIN TRY

OPEN CUR1
   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO ...



END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   RETURN
END CATCH

SET @RC = 0
RETURN
```

Should I close the Cursor inside the try or does it not matter. What I am unsure of is if my code in the try goes into the CATCH then the cursor may not get closed.

How is this normally dealt with?  Also is they way I have my RETURN after the CATCH the normal way to code a return

Thanks

Comment: Before the `end try`

Comment: So then if my code has an exception is it okay that the cursor won't get closed ?

Comment: What if it errors out before reaching the close command?

Comment: Then you should close it in the error handler also, that is your `Catch` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would close it before then `END TRY`. Additionally, I would add a check if the cursor is still open and close it if it is. See here for more info: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic767778-338-1.aspx

```
BEGIN TRY

OPEN CUR1
   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO ...

CLOSE CUR1
DEALLOCATE test_cursor

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @curStatus = Cursor_Status('local', 'CUR1'); --set it to LOCAL above, if using global above change here too
    IF @curStatus >= 0 
    BEGIN
        CLOSE objectsCur;
        DEALLOCATE objectsCur;
    END
    ELSE IF @curStatus = -1 --may have been closed already so just deallocate
    BEGIN
        DEALLOCATE objectsCur;
    END
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define your cursors as LOCAL if there's no need for having them as global.

Meaning of LOCAL from BOL:

> Specifies that the scope of the cursor is local to the batch, stored
>   procedure, or trigger in which the cursor was created. The cursor name
>   is only valid within this scope. The cursor can be referenced by local
>   cursor variables in the batch, stored procedure, or trigger, or a
>   stored procedure OUTPUT parameter. An OUTPUT parameter is used to pass
>   the local cursor back to the calling batch, stored procedure, or
>   trigger, which can assign the parameter to a cursor variable to
>   reference the cursor after the stored procedure terminates. The cursor
>   is **implicitly deallocated** when the batch, stored procedure, or trigger
>   terminates, unless the cursor was passed back in an OUTPUT parameter.
>   If it is passed back in an OUTPUT parameter, the cursor is deallocated
>   when the last variable referencing it is deallocated or goes out of
>   scope.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Using also FORWARD_ONLY and READ ONLY (or FAST_FORWARD) when that's what you need is a good practice. It will make cursors a lot faster.

Comment: James - Thanks for these suggestions. Yes in this case I would only need read only and forward only. Can you show how these could be used.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to close the cursor inside the block that it has been declared, that is the `TRY` but it should also be deallocated in the error handler, that is the `catch` part;

```
BEGIN TRY

OPEN CUR1
   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO ...


CLOSE CUR1;
DEALLOCATE CUR1;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   CLOSE CUR1;
   DEALLOCATE CUR1;
   RETURN
END CATCH

SET @RC = 0
RETURN
```